# how to make my users access to their own bucket in my application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm thinking to make my user access to their own s3 bucket so they can load and display their image in my web application.

user come to my web -> click UI -> login and auth -> select images -> display it.

Is this scenario possible? how?
I'm using react for my front-end and node.js for my backend..

Do I use any file trasnfer protocol? or how to bring image from s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript in your frontend and node js in your backend you will need to use the [AWS JS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) with the [AWS.S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) class to perform all interactions.

You should look at storing the assets with a prefix of the username to make it easier to list objects (rather than `image.jpg` you would store at `username/image.jpg`).

To upload you would make use of the [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) function, with the [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) function to list passing in the prefix.

You can further enhance this by using a [Cognito User Pool](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to manage the authentication. You can enhance the security by making use of the [${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) variable in your IAM policy to restrict access to only the users specific prefix in S3.

Comment: So I was thinking, when an user comes to my web, they first need to sign up or sign in and then, once he sign in, he can access to his own s3 bucket. I don't want them to upload anything into my bucket. So they must have their image uploaded to their own bucket. Is this possible with cognito? or should user need to upload in my bucket? which way is possible?

Comment: Hmm, you couldn't do this in permissions for cognito as the format for the value would appear like `us-east-1:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456790ab`. In this case your app would need to use an IAM role on the instance and manage the bucket name on the backend of the application (in your NodeJS).

Comment: Just like people load their image from google cloud storage. I wanted know if it is possible with s3 bucket.

Comment: Right, I haven't experience in google cloud storage but with S3 people would tend to make an S3 bucket for an application and then use a prefix to separate out per username :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Cognito fur the authentication part.

The easiest way to archive what you want is to use AWS amplify.
[See here](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/?nc1=h_ls)
Follow [this guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/js#install-and-configure-the-amplify-cli) for step by step instructions for node.js